# FSK carrier frequency estimation in non equiprobable data

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, non-linear

We know that in equiprobable data,change in phase over a time interval, this result will be directly proportional to frequency: 
f∝Im(s(n)s(n−1)∗)
Where s(n) is the normalized complex FSK time domain signal.

In the MPSK Modulations, Cyclic Spectrum Density method can give a peaks, for example for the QPSK:

[image]

But in the in the non equiprobable FSK signal, this peaks do'nt appear. How to solve it?

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, I think you're confusing something: frequency is **defined** as change in phase over time, that has nothing to do with FSK, or the data. It always is true – it's a definition.

Comment: @Marcus Müller I ediited my question.